# how to get multiple values from a json array/object using jq

Tags: shell, jq

how to get multiple values from a JSON array/object using jq in a single line?

here curl request and its response

```
curl -s -k --location --request GET "https://${HOSTNAME}/api/v1/projects/myProjects?page=1&pageSize=2" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" | jq -r '.["data"]'


# Response
[
  {
    "id": "8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d",
    "createdBy": "8a70802980325cdc0180326b5fe60006",
    "createdDate": "2022-04-22T03:48:38.860+0000",
    "modifiedBy": "8a70802980325cdc0180326b5fe60006",
    "modifiedDate": "2022-04-22T03:48:38.860+0000",
    "version": null,
    "inactive": false,
    "name": "Netbank734113",
  },
  {
    "id": "8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d",
    "createdBy": "8a70802980325cdc0180326b5fe60006",
    "createdDate": "2022-04-22T03:48:07.442+0000",
    "modifiedBy": "8a70802980325cdc0180326b5fe60006",
    "modifiedDate": "2022-04-22T03:48:07.442+0000",
    "version": null,
    "inactive": false,
    "name": "Netbank734112",
  }
]
```

Now try the below command to get the id and name in one line but duplicate results are coming.

```
result=$(curl -s -k --location --request GET "https://${HOSTNAME}/api/v1/projects/myProjects?page=1&pageSize=2" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" | jq -r '.["data"]|.[].name +" "+  .[].id')

echo "$result"

# response
Netbank734113 8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d
Netbank734112 8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d
Netbank734113 8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d
Netbank734112 8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d
```

how do I get rid of those duplicated values and basically get the below response?

```
Netbank734113 8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d
Netbank734112 8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d
```

Tried this command with your inputs getting the below errors, how do I modify this curl command to get desired results.

```
result=$(curl -s -k --location --request GET "https://${HOSTNAME}/api/v1/projects/myProjects?page=1&pageSize=2" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" | jq -r '["data"]|.[].unique_by(.name, .id) | map([.name, .id])[] | @tsv')

# error response

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
["data"]|.[].unique_by(.name, .id) | map([.name, .id])[] | @tsv                      
jq: 1 compile error
 
# This one worked
result=$(curl -s -k --location --request GET "https://${HOSTNAME}/api/v1/projects/myProjects?page=1&pageSize=2" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" | jq -r '.["data"]|.[]|.| .name + " " + .id')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `.[].name + " " + .[].id'` you iterate twice over the array. Iterate once and extract your data in one go:

```sh
curl … | jq -r '.data[] | .name + " " + .id'
```

```
Netbank734113 8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d
Netbank734112 8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZJ2MpA4D9q)

---

You might also be interested in using string interpolation:

```sh
curl … | jq -r '.data[] | "\(.name) \(.id)"'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jEE9mmCmg7)

Comment: `.name + " " + .id` works if both are a string, but doesn't work if the id is a number.

Comment: @AlexxRoche `(.id | tostring)` or `(.id | @text)` or said string interpolation can be used to convert to string, if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

you could take the output of jq and use the unix shell to de-duplicate the output ...

command_output | sort | uniq

Comment: Question specifically asked to get the data through jq